# PowerShell script to send email when IP changes is returning empty IP strings

Tags: powershell, ip, ip-address

I have a script that checks for changes in my IP address and emails a notification when it changes. The email will contain the new IP as well as the previous IP. I run this script on several different computers using different internet connections / providers. One of these computers often generates a notification of an IP change but the old IP listed is blank and the current IP listed is the same as the last known IP.

I cannot reproduce a blank value and the portion of my script that would deal with a blank value is not triggering. I tried disconnecting my network cable and running the script, I tried putting a bogus api address in. It seems that no matter what, if an exception occurs the script will keep the last good value and not generate a notification or update with a blank.

Any ideas or workarounds?

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 

[string]$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath  

set-location $dir



$Logfile = "C:\IPChangeNotifier\Site_IP.log"



Function LogWrite

{

   Param ([string]$logstring)



   Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring

}



$oldip = gc .\ip.txt

Write-Host "Your previous IP was: $oldip"

$currentip = (New-Object net.webclient).downloadstring("http://api.ipify.org")

while ($currentip -eq '') {$currentip = (New-Object net.webclient).downloadstring("http://api.ipify.org")}

Write-Host "Your current IP is: $currentip"

$smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"

$sender = "address@gmail.com"

$users = "user1@gmail.com", "user2@gmail.com", "user3@gmail.com";

if ($currentip){

    $subject = "Site IP Change! $currentip"

    $body = "Previous IP was $oldip"  

#if $currentip is empty.. 
} else {  

    $subject = "Site IP cannot be found!"

    $body = "Last known IP was $oldip, check the connection at the site or check that the api.ipify.org site is up and running."

}

$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer, 587) 

$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 

$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("email_user", "email_pword"); 





if ($oldip -ne $currentip) {

    foreach ($user in $users) {

    Write-Host "Sending email notification to $user" -ForegroundColor Green

    $SMTPClient.Send($sender, $user, $Subject, $Body)

    $LogTime = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

    LogWrite "$LogTime $currentip"

    }

}



$currentip | Out-File .\ip.txt -Force

Write-Host "New IP saved in file is: $currentip"
```

The log looks like this:

```
08/28/2016 02:00:37 
08/28/2016 02:00:49 
08/28/2016 02:01:01 
08/28/2016 09:00:07 72.5.219.226
08/28/2016 09:00:09 72.5.219.226
08/28/2016 09:00:10 72.5.219.226
08/29/2016 10:00:34 
08/29/2016 10:00:47 
08/29/2016 10:00:59 
08/29/2016 11:00:07 72.5.219.226
08/29/2016 11:00:08 72.5.219.226
08/29/2016 11:00:10 72.5.219.226
08/29/2016 06:00:37 
08/29/2016 06:00:49 
08/29/2016 06:01:01 
08/29/2016 07:00:07 72.5.219.226
08/29/2016 07:00:09 72.5.219.226
08/29/2016 07:00:10 72.5.219.226
```

Emails were generated as follows:

```
8/28 9:01 Site IP Change! 72.5.219.226, Previous IP was 
8/29 11:01 Site IP Change! 72.5.219.226, Previous IP was 
8/29 7:00 Site IP Change! 72.5.219.226, Previous IP was
```

Version info:

```
Name                           Value                                                    
----                           -----                                                    
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5485                                           
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514                                           
PSVersion                      2.0                                                      
WSManStackVersion              2.0                                                      
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}                                               
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                  
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Comment: Judging by the code, this could happen if `ip.txt` was empty or deleted for some unknown reason.

Comment: But the log writes a blank value too. I'm assuming ip.txt is also blank during this time. I'm trying to figure out whats causing the blank.

Comment: In case the network is down, `$currentip` will be `$null`. To correctly handle this you need to replace `while ($currentip -eq '')` with `while (!$currentip)`

Comment: I will try this, thank you.

Comment: much like @wOxxOm I think the issue is your `While` statement. I would use `While([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($currentip))` to make sure that `$currentip` is neither blank or null.